# Remote sensing product data catalog?

Tags: remote-sensing

Since there are a huge number of remote sensing products available, I feel confused.  Is there any data catalog for data specification, date of acquisition, and type of application?

Comment: Welcome as a user on gis.stackexchange.com! Your question is pretty broad and not really find one answer. The answers will be pointing you in the direction of different product related overviews. USGS will have their data catalog, while others will have no public information about their products. If you have particular interests within remote sensing data you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reverb|Echo](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/) is one of the best collections of RS data available.  Although it is initially difficult to navigate, you will find that you can search by science keywords, platforms & instruments, campaigns, and processing levels.